# How can I find a rails object based on the properties of their has_many :through relations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through

Models: Foo, Bar, Bonk

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars
  has_many :bonks, :through => :bars
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bonks
end
```

How can I retrieve a list of **Foo** objects that are associated with a Bonk whose name is "awesome"

I know how to do with with a Foo.find(...) that involves a :join and a :condition. What I want to do though is avoid shoving that much raw sql into there (especially when there's more than one model in the middle).

Something like

```
Foo.find(:all, :conditions=>["bonks.name = ?", 'awesome'])
```

which, obviously, doesn't work as it'd generate

```
Select * from foos where bonks.name = 'awesome'
```

Sadly, I'm dealing with a rails 1.2 app here but I don't *think* this functionality has changed since then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Foo.find(:all, :conditions=>["bonks.name = ?", 'awesome'], :include => :bonks)
```

should generate something along the lines of

```
Select * from foos, bars, bonks where bars.foo_id = foo.id and bonks.bar_id = bar.id and bonks.name = 'awesome'
```

Comment: it generated `select .... FROM foos  LEFT OUTER JOIN bars ON (foo."id" = bar."foo_id")  LEFT OUTER JOIN bonks ON (bonks."bar_id" = bars."id") WHERE (bonks.name= 'awesome')`

Comment: Yeah I shorthanded all the joins instead of doing OUTERS like Rails does - sorry bout that, glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

In 1.2 - an SQL fragment in a `:joins` argument is your best choice here.  There's no better way to do this.